# Update an MySql row with a textarea in PHP with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Just before the actual question, I have found some sites showing how to do this but they were using the old mysql method. I am looking for a PDO method.**

So I am trying to update an MySQL row (only one column) using PHP and html. All I have is an variable that points to the column I want:

```
$about = DB::query('SELECT about FROM users WHERE username=:username',
                   array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['about'];
```

And I want to have an  with textarea and a button that are updating the row.

Comment: Ok so that looks like it fetches the data from MYSQL to PHP. Are you expecting us to write all the rest or the code you say you require **????** Thats not how SO works. **You** code it, and if you have problems **we try and help you fix it**.

Comment: `UPDATE user SET about = :about WHERE username=:username`

Comment: @RiggsFolly 1. I am looking for an 1-line query 2. Your edit is wrong. It's one line, not two lines.

Comment: But it does not have to be coded on one liner. and as I had it we can actually read it without scrolling

Comment: I would not have changed it if I believed I was changing anything syntactically important

Comment: And I am not sure how this _And I want to have an with textarea and a button that are updating the row._ could be answered in 1 Line